# error in loading multiple excel files in r

Tags: r, regex, excel, merge

How to load multiple excel files using the loop in R:

I have already tried in R but got an error which stated:

> Error in loadWorkbook(file, password = password) : 
>     Cannot find FAF_Clustering_April_2018.xlsx

I tried with this code:

```
file.list <- list.files(path=".../Desktop/clustering" , pattern='*.xlsx')
dat = lapply(file.list, function(i){
x = read.xlsx(i, sheetIndex=1, startRow=1, as.data.frame=TRUE, header=TRUE)
x })
```

How to find the way to solve this problem?

Marjan

Comment: Did you read your Error message? It seems pretty clear from it where the issue lies

Comment: `setwd(".../Desktop/clustering")`

Comment: Try to add parameter `full.names = TRUE` to `list.files()`

Comment: @Ape It works. thank you!